# Работа с Telegram Bot: как создать webHook и запуск бота на сервере

Tags: python, python-3.x, сервер, telegram-bot, telegram

Начал писать *Teleram Bot* на *Python 3.5* и для того, чтобы бот отвечал автономно на сообщения от пользователя нужно запустить бота на сервере и начать работу с *webHook-ом*. Если кто работал и писал бота, то напишите, пожалуйста, пошаговую инструкцию, как работать/создать *webHook* и запуск бота на сервере (беспланый сервер), а то я понятия не имею как это делается.

Comment: WebHook не единственный способ, другой вариант - опрашивать через getUpdates (long poll), при этом не потребуется внешний IP и запускать можно с домашнего компьютера или даже смартфона.  [Пример](https://github.com/vladimirgamalian/OMFTB)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам нужно запускать бота для разработки, а не на постоянной основе, то можно использовать long_poll.
Если же нужно держать бота на постоянной основе, то да, лучше использовать вебхук.
Инструкция:
1)Создать самоподписанный сертификат
2)Создать сервер в боте
3)Запустить
Более подробная информация есть на сайте groosha.gitbooks.io

Answer (score 1):

Сервером может быть что угодно, где запущен скрипт с вашим ботом.
Попробуйте этот фреймворк https://github.com/nickoala/telepot
Там неплохие примеры поэтому сложностей возникнуть не должно.